# How to add new value for a given dimension and coordinate in xarray?

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I have data with the following xarray DataSet representation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'var': np.random.rand(16),
    'country': 4*['UK'] + 4*['US'] + 4*['FR'] + 4*['DE'],
    'time_delta': 4*list(pd.timedelta_range(
        start='30D',
        periods=4,
        freq='30D'
    )),
})

ds = df.set_index(['country','time_delta']).to_xarray()
```

I want to add new value of the variable for a given new coord and a given dimension while maintaining the existing dimensions:

> Set value=0 of variable=var for coord='0D' of dimension=time_delta while preserving other existing
> dimensions (in that case country).

In pandas I can do this via:

```
# 1. Pivot long to wide
df_wide = df.pivot(
    index='country',
    columns='time_delta'
).droplevel(0,axis=1)

# 2. Set value
df_wide['0D'] = 0

# 3. Melt wide to long
df_new = df_wide.melt(ignore_index=False).rename(
    columns={'value': 'var'}
).reset_index()

ds_new = df_new.set_index(['country','time_delta']).to_xarray()
```

Is there a general way of making such operations in xarray in order to achieve directly `ds -> ds_new`?

**Edit**: The below fails with message that: "KeyError: "not all values found in index 'time_delta'"

```
ds['var'].loc[{'time_delta': '0D'}] = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Xarray, you can achieve the same result using the following approach. Here's the code to perform the operation you described:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# Original dataset creation
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'var': np.random.rand(16),
    'country': 4*['UK'] + 4*['US'] + 4*['FR'] + 4*['DE'],
    'time_delta': 4*list(pd.timedelta_range(
        start='30D',
        periods=4,
        freq='30D'
    )),
})

ds = df.set_index(['country', 'time_delta']).to_xarray()

# Adding new value for the given coordinate and dimension
ds_new = ds.copy()  # Make a copy to avoid modifying the original 
dataset

# Add a new coordinate to the 'time_delta' dimension
new_time_delta = pd.to_timedelta(['0D'])
ds_new['var'] = xr.concat([ds_new['var'], xr.DataArray([0], 
dims='time_delta', coords={'time_delta': new_time_delta})], 
dim='time_delta')

# Display the new dataset
print(ds_new)
```

***This is an edited version of the original answer!**

This code makes use of Xarray's `.loc` accessor to set the value of the 'var' variable to 0 for the specified coordinate ('0D') in the 'time_delta' dimension. This operation modifies the `ds_new` dataset while keeping the original `ds` dataset unchanged.

Comment: Thanks but setting with loc fails for me with the following message: <KeyError: "not all values found in index 'time_delta'. Try setting the `method` keyword argument (example: method='nearest').> I am using pandas '1.5.3' and xarray '2023.10.1'

Comment: When I first saw the error message with .loc I though that assigning to not currently existing index is not supported...

Comment: @Konstantin you can use the reindex method before assigning the value. Here's an updated version of the code: https://pastebin.com/raw/z90PWUCd

Comment: This doesn't work either "unhashable type: 'DataArray'", can you please test your solutions.

Comment: @Konstantin Sorry it seems I overlooked the error here the correct code: https://pastebin.com/raw/rBg0Gd1T

Comment: Thank you so much, please edit your reply and I will mark it as accepted!